# Pattern for javascript instantiation which doesn't upset eslint

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, eslint, clipboard.js

I've seen plenty of libraries which use the following pattern - e.g. [clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/) which I've just been working with:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard(".cpy");
```

That's all it needs to do its magic. But that annoys ESLint:

```
clipboard is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)
```

Some workarounds I've looked at are:

- a spurious `console.log()` call to 'use' `clipboard`
- `/* exported clipboard */` - but I can't get this to work (perhaps my eslint needs updating?)
- `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */` - and hope for the best elsewhere in the project
- put a `varsIgnorePattern` into options - not a very 'quick' solution, and different for each project

I'm not very happy with any of those. But, is there a 'better' pattern than `var x = new X();` for instantiating a library? Or a better way to tell ESLint what's going on?

Comment: can you just do `new Clipboard(".cpy")` without saving the reference?

Comment: What about `var clipboard = null;` and then `clipboard = new Clipboard(".cpy");` ?

Comment: @Mathletics That also causes ESLint to spit out an error - don't use new for side effects!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this PR](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/1840) you can now do per-line ignores:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.cpy') // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

This will only affect this line and not leave your codebase open to unused vars everywhere.

You could previously do the same with:

```
/*eslint-disable no-eval*/
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.cpy');
/*eslint-enable*/
```

Comment: One `npm update -g eslint` later and all is well. Many thanks!

Comment: Gah! Spoke too soon. Now my ST linter has stopped working with the updated eslint... One of those days.

Comment: @dsl101 woof, don't install globally unless you absolutely have to!

Comment: Well, it was installed globally before. Anyway, turned out the problem was that from 0.6 to 1.0, ESLint disabled all the default rules, and I hadn't spotted that! All back to normal-ish now

Comment: The correct code seems to be `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars` - it was changed halfway down that PR you referenced...

Answer (score 2):

ESLint is just right here. If you don't need the instance, there's no need to store it in a variable:

```
new Clipboard('.cpy'); // eslint-disable-line no-new
// no `var clipboard`
```

Of course, executing side effects through a constructor is kind of an antipattern, but if `Clipboard` works that way, there's no way around it.

Comment: Yeah - that still leaves the ESLint error marker as you suggest - Do not use 'new' for side effects. Grr.

Comment: @dsl101: Then rather disable that rule than the unused-variables one. Because it is the one you really want/need to break here.

Comment: True - I suppose it's much less likely to result in missed problems elsewhere. However, for debugging, I sometimes would want to `console.log(clipboard);` during development and there are also events you can attach to via `clipboard.on()`, so for now I'll go for the first answer. I don't think I can mark this as 'correct' as well though can I?

Comment: No, you can accept only one answer, though you can upvote them both :-)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically shouldn't there be some cleaning up after use?

```
 clipboard.destroy();
```

Comment: Yes, but separate issue I think. This was specifically about ESLint rules and whether there is a better instantiation pattern for libraries which use side effects of constructors...